# Putting output into a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a batch file that sets the JAVA_HOME.

Now I have the following code that looks for if a path exists. 
If that is the case I would like to store the complete name in a variable.

```
set javaLoc=
set javaLoc=$(dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8*" /s/b) 
echo %javaLoc%
```

But the echo returns me:

```
$(dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8*" /s/b)
```

While I would like to capture the output (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40) from it in "javaLoc".

I also tried:

```
dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8*" /s/b > javaLoc
```

But also that doesn't work. 
Can anyone help me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with a `FOR` statement, where you'd make `javaLoc` the iteration variable. Type `FOR /?` on a command-line prompt to see a list of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're coming in with experience from bash (or possibly kornshell). Sadly, batch is a bit more limited than it's *nix counterpart, so you can't directly store the output of a command in a variable.

You *can*, however, run the command through a `for /F` loop and store the result in a variable that way, like this:

```
for /F %%A in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8*" /s /b') do (
    set javaLoc=%%A
)
```

Although it should be noted that if there is more than one item returned by this command, javaLoc will be set to the last one in the list.

Comment: That worked for me. I did add a "delims=" in it for the whitespaces.